# reset() - "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Tags: php, reference, strict

I am currently moving a website over for a client. Their old host must be using an old version of PHP from what I can gather. The site is currently working on their current host. I am working to move this to a new host for them and I am getting the following error:

> PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/parcelt2/core/public_html/loader.php on line 17

Below is a section of code with line 17 marked out

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (substr($uri['path'], -1, 1) == '/' && !sizeof($_POST)) {
$new_uri = substr($uri['path'], 0, -1);
if (strlen($new_uri) > 0) {
    $page = reset(explode('/', $new_uri));  //line 17
    if (!in_array($page, $exempt_requests)) {
        if (isset($uri['query']) && strlen($uri['query']) > 0) {
            $new_uri .= '?' . $uri['query'];
        }
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: ' . $new_uri, true, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
}
```

Would anyone be able to provide a fix or some suggestion on how to fix this? I have tried reading other SO posts about this error but have found them hard to understand.

Thank you

Comment: Ok, you're getting an error. What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: I wonder what `reset` is doing here. There's a brand new array created by `explode`, which has its pointer in a prime position - pointing to the very first element, that is.

Comment: You need to store the result of explode call in a variable then pass the variable to the reset function

Comment: I do not know what reset is doing here. I am not the developer of the code. I simply am trying to move it from an old host and this is what is showing in an error log. Thank you

Comment: Remember to search for the error message. This is not a new issue.

Comment: @BHWD But you still have to change the code to get rid of this error, don't you think? ) I'd rather have `reset` call removed than introduce another variable just for it to go without an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[reset()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.reset.php) takes a reference to an array (variable) so it will not work with the result of a function call.

You need to do something like this:

```
$arr = explode('/', $new_uri);
$page = reset($arr);
```

However, the array returned by `explode()` will already have its internal pointer set to the first element. You shouldn't need to call reset at all.

Comment: But what's `reset` for here?

Comment: @raina77ow heh...good point. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I do not know what reset is doing here. I am not the developer of the code. I simply am trying to move it from an old host and this is what is showing in an error log. Thank you

Comment: Would you be able to show me how that code would fit into what I have posted above? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: @BHWD your error was caused by using `reset()` on the result of a function, not a variable reference. However, you don't need to use reset at all. Just remove it on your line 17.

Comment: I have removed reset so the code looks like '$page = (explode('/', $new_uri));' however I still get the same error in the error logs.

Comment: Well, you don't need the extra parentheses there at all, but it will run all the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56374/discussion-between-bhwd-and--).

Comment: Reset() Returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is empty